# Android : Application is crashing on Nexus 7

Tags: android

I'm building an application targeting all the devices for Android. But I'm not able to run the application specifically on Nexus 7. I have checked through all the possibilities present on the stackoverflow, but I'm not able to recover from this problem. I'm pasting my AndroidManifest file here. Please see and correct me where I'm doing wrong.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" >
</supports-screens>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

<!-- Mobclix Required Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<!-- Mobclix Optional Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:name=".AppSingleton"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AppWidgetConfigure"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- widget stuff -->
    <receiver android:name=".MyAppWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/my_appwidget_info" />
    </receiver>

    <!-- Mobclix Required Parameter -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.mobclix.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="6D72xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixBrowserActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="UserPreference"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Please give me some suggestion for that.

DDMS Error Log:

`09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jutera.allsearch/com.jutera.allsearch.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at com.jutera.allsearch.MainActivity.connectionAvailable(MainActivity.java:748)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at com.jutera.allsearch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:159)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
09-24 16:26:48.424: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):     ... 11 more
09-24 16:26:51.684: D/dalvikvm(2213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 368K, 10% free 7726K/8519K, paused 12ms+12ms, total 46ms`

Comment: please provide your log on the crash

Comment: I have added the error log. Please have a look and guide me where am I wrong.

Comment: Solved that. Checking connection is not being supported in Nexus 7, I dont'know why? But if you have any idea regarding this please tell me becuase now ForceClose is not coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked for me! There was some problem with how I check my internet connection. Here is my solved code:

```
/**
 * Checking network state
 * */
public boolean connectionAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<supports-screens android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"></supports-screens>
```

see above code and add support for xlargeScreens!